# JSON.parse in react-native + axios

Tags: json, react-native, axios

I'm using axios to fetch data from an API in PHP. I get a response with the expected data in react-native, however, when using the `JSON.parse()` function, I get the error:

> "[SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '']".

I have already validated the response I receive with the tool available at `https://jsonlint.com/`

The complete response I get is:

```
{"config": {"adapter": [Function xhrAdapter], "baseURL": "baseurl.com.br", "data": "{\"data\":{\"codPedido\":\"67912\",\"codLoja\":\"3\",\"action\":\"getPedido\"}}", "headers": {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"}, "maxBodyLength": -1, "maxContentLength": -1, "method": "post", "timeout": 0, "transformRequest": [[Function transformRequest]], "transformResponse": [[Function transformResponse]], "url": "/request.php", "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus], "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"}, "data": "{\"status\":\"success\",\"type\":true,\"data\":{\"codLoja\":\"3\",\"codPedido\":\"67912\"}}", "headers": {"connection": "Keep-Alive", "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "date": "Mon, 23 Nov 2020 18:27:54 GMT", "keep-alive": "timeout=5, max=100", "server": "Apache", "vary": "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent"}, "request": {"DONE": 4, "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2, "LOADING": 3, "OPENED": 1, "UNSENT": 0, "_aborted": false, "_cachedResponse": undefined, "_hasError": false, "_headers": {"accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"}, "_incrementalEvents": false, "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {"connection": "Keep-Alive", "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "date": "Mon, 23 Nov 2020 18:27:54 GMT", "keep-alive": "timeout=5, max=100", "server": "Apache", "vary": "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent"}, "_method": "POST", "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_https://baseurl.com.br/request.php", "_requestId": null, "_response": "{\"status\":\"success\",\"type\":true,\"data\":{\"codLoja\":\"3\",\"codPedido\":\"67912\"}}", "_responseType": "", "_sent": true, "_subscriptions": [], "_timedOut": false, "_trackingName": "unknown", "_url": "baseurl.com.br/request.php", "readyState": 4, "responseHeaders": {"Connection": "Keep-Alive", "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "Date": "Mon, 23 Nov 2020 18:27:54 GMT", "Keep-Alive": "timeout=5, max=100", "Server": "Apache", "Vary": "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent"}, "responseURL": "baseurl.com.br/request.php", "status": 200, "timeout": 0, "upload": {}, "withCredentials": true}, "status": 200, "statusText": undefined}
```

I try to use JSON.parse:

```
 api.post('/request.php', {
            data: { codPedido, codLoja, action: 'getPedido' },  
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(JSON.parse(data.data));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
```

Has anyone been through this or know what I may be doing wrong?

Versions:

- react-native: 0.63.3
- axios: 0.21.0
- API PHP: 5.6.40
- LG K50S (android 9)

Answer (score 0):

parse the main object then then access data from it

**try this**

```
.then(data => {
            const jsonObj= JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(jsonObj.data);
            
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The object data is already... an object. 
I can access the property data using `data.data`. `console.log(data.data)` prints expected result. However i couldn't use `JSON.parse(data.data)` with success